# how to solve array to get as individuals

Tags: php

i have an array structure like below

```html
Array
(
    [0] => ICRAF Subjects
    [1] => Agriculture/Agroforestry
    [2] => ICRAF Subjects
    [3] => Natural Resource Management
    [4] => Science Domains
    [5] => SD4-Land health decisions
    [6] => Uncategorized
)

Array
(
    [0] => ICRAF Subjects
    [1] => Agriculture/Agroforestry
    [2] => ICRAF Subjects
    [3] => Natural Resource Management
    [4] => Science Domains
    [5] => SD4-Land health decisions
    [6] => Sustainable development Goals SDG
    [7] => SDG13-Climate change
)

Array
(
    [0] => Uncategorized
)

Array
(
    [0] => ICRAF Subjects
    [1] => Agriculture/Agroforestry
)
```

how can i get it as

```html
(
     ICRAF Subjects
     Agriculture/Agroforestry
     ICRAF Subjects
     Natural Resource Management
     Science Domains
     SD4-Land health decisions
     Uncategorized
)

(        ICRAF Subjects
    Agriculture/Agroforestry
    ICRAF Subjects
    Natural Resource Management
    Science Domains
    SD4-Land health decisions
    Sustainable development Goals SDG
    SDG13-Climate change
)

(
    Uncategorized
)

(
    ICRAF Subjects
    Agriculture/Agroforestry
)
```

Comment: use foreach and iterate through each array

Comment: i have used foreach loop but getting only last element @vSugumar Sugumar

Comment: So post your code here so everybody can see what you've tried

Comment: @Moby M please try my code and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use foreach to loop and iterate over each array and print it

```
$array1 = array('ICRAF Subjects','Agriculture/Agroforestry','ICRAF Subjects','Natural Resource Management','Science Domains','SD4-Land health decisions','Uncategorized',
    );

    $array2 = array(
    'ICRAF Subjects',
    'Agriculture/Agroforestry',
    'ICRAF Subjects',
    'Natural Resource Management',
    'Science Domains',
    'SD4-Land health decisions',
    'Sustainable development Goals SDG',
    'SDG13-Climate change',
    );

    $array3 = array
    (
    'Uncategorized',
    );

    $array4 = Array
    (
    'ICRAF Subjects',
    'Agriculture/Agroforestry',
    );

    $newarr = [$array1, $array2, $array3, $array4];

    foreach($newarr as $arr){
    echo '<br>';
      echo '(';
      echo '<br>';
      foreach($arr as $ar){
        echo $ar;
        echo '<br>';
      }

      echo ')';
    echo '<br>';
    }
```